# New line in cursor-intangible area and line-beginning position

Tags: motion, text-properties

I want to make the beginning of a line uneditable, which I can achieve by applying the `read-only` and `cursor-intangible` properties. But I have the problem, that `line-beginning-position` moves point not to the first reachable position of the current line, as I expect, but to the end of the previous line. This may be a bug in Emacs. Is there some workaround for this issue?

Example:
Let's say buffer contains "blablabla\nINTANGIBLEfooooo" INTANGIBLE has properties cursor-intangible t rear-nonsticky t front-sticky t. Then it is not possible to put point before any symbol of "INTANGIBLE", that is exactly wanted behavior, however if point is somewhere in fooooo, move-beginning-of-line puts point to the end of blablabla, which is strange.

Reconstruction:

- Copy and paste the following form into the `*scratch*` buffer. There the black rectangle ▮ indicates the point position. (You should not copy that character.)

```el
(insert "\nblablabla\n"
        (propertize "INTANGIBLE" 'cursor-intangible t 'rear-nonsticky t 'front-sticky t)
        "fooooo")▮
```

- Eval the form with <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>. You get

```el
(insert "\nblablabla\n"
        (propertize "INTANGIBLE" 'cursor-intangible t 'rear-nonsticky t 'front-sticky t)
        "fooooo")
blablabla
INTANGIBLEfooooo▮
```

- Hit the <kbd>home</kbd> key.
  You end up with:

```el
(insert "\nblablabla\n" (propertize "INTANGIBLE" 'cursor-intangible t 'rear-nonsticky t 'front-sticky t) "fooooo")
blablabla▮
INTANGIBLEfooooo
```

---

It becomes really interesting if one tries to get this behavior completely with the evaluation of a lisp expression:

```el
(progn
  (insert "\nblablabla\n"
          (propertize "INTANGIBLE" 'cursor-intangible t 'rear-nonsticky t 'front-sticky t)
          "fooooo")
  (call-interactively #'move-beginning-of-line))▮
```

After evaluation with <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> one gets:
[image: lisp form evaluation]

I.e., point is between the last intangentiable character and the `f` of `foooooo`.

Comment: Solved by applying field property to intangible area.

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer (which you can accept). Try to make clear what the problem was and show how the solution solves it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour. With point at BOL, `(progn (add-text-properties (point) (1+ (point)) '(read-only t cursor-intangible t)) (cursor-intangible-mode) (end-of-line) (beginning-of-line))` takes me back to where I started. Note that the function `line-beginning-position` which you mention does not move point.

Comment: You get the effect of the OP if you use a wrong beginning: `(progn (add-text-properties (1- (point)) (1+ (point)) '(read-only t cursor-intangible t)) (cursor-intangible-mode) (end-of-line) (beginning-of-line))`. Maybe something like that was the cause.

Comment: @Tobias Yes, and this is expected behaviour for `cursor-intangible-mode`. Drew is right in that OP should provide more information about what they are trying to do and how.

Answer (score 4):

Applying field property to intangible area solves the problem.

Adding of field t to the properties of INTANGIBLE makes move-beginning-of-line putting point between INTANGIBLE and fooooo, like expected.

Reconstruction:

- Copy-paste following lisp code into the `*scratch*` buffer. There the black rectangle ▮ indicates the point position. (You should not copy that character.)

```el
(insert "\nblablabla\n"
        (propertize "INTANGIBLE"
                    'cursor-intangible t
                    'rear-nonsticky t
                    'front-sticky t
                    'field t)
        "fooooo")▮
```

- Evaluate it with <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>.
- Press the <kbd>home</kbd> key. You get:

[image: final state of *scratch* with field-propertized string]

I.e., point is between the last intangentiable character and the `f` of `foooooo`.

Comment: Please provide a more complete answer so that other users who find this post later will understand what you did.

Comment: Sorry about that downvote -- the flagging system did it automatically.  If you can expand your answer to be more explanatory, I will upvote to compensate.

Comment: @Dan Does the flagging system automatically reverse the downvote if all close-votes have been retracted?

Comment: @Tobias : I’m sorry, I don’t know.